# firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider not providing a user on redirect

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use the Firebase GoogleAuthProvider with a redirect flow.

I have a plain provider:
`var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()`, and I initiate the flow on a sign-in button: `firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)`

`getRedirectResult` is mysteriously giving me a `null` user. I get no errors. The following is run on page load:

```
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
  console.log('Redirect result', result)
}).catch(function(err){
  console.error('Redirect error', err);
})
```

It seems like it should work:

- The redirect flow takes me to the Google OAuth page, where I'm signed in and click "allow." It redirects me to firebaseapp.com which redirects to my test domain
- Google Auth is enabled in the Firebase console
- My test domain is whitelisted as an OAuth redirect domain
- I've initialized the firebase app with `authDomain` (`<my id>.firebaseapp.com`) and `apiKey`

The docs suggest "If no redirect operation was called, returns a UserCredential with a null User," but it returns `null` regardless of whether it's the initial load of the test page or the OAuth redirect. Is there an incantation I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? Can you provide more information on the environment, browser name/version, OS where you are testing this. Please try to test in another browser to make sure your config settings are correct. Also, you could also check signInWithPopup works to help isolate this issue to redirect and not some other reason.

Comment: Thanks! I don't get any console errors. This is up-to-date Chrome on OS X. Will test on Safari when I get back. I did see that signInWithPopup timed out -- the window would appear, I would click allow, and then I would get a console error that the popup timed out. So probably an issue with GoogleAuthProvider generally.

Comment: Tested: identical code works in Safari, does not work in Chrome (52.)

Comment: I am seeing this same thing

Comment: What was the solution to this?